# Manually start uwsgi with python3.6 and python2 and django 2

Tags: django, uwsgi

I just started to use uWSGI and Django. I want to invoke it manually.
I'm using python36, Django 2 and if I install uWSGI (`pip install uwsgi`) in venv and everything is ok.

Q1. When using outside of venv I first installed uWSGI:

`pip install uwsgi` -> 2.0.18 version

Installed plugins: `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Trying to run with python36:

`uwsgi  --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins --plugin python3 --master --http :5000 --home ~/my_playground/webapps/  --chdir ~/my_playground/webapps/p_tscze/ --module p_tscze.wsgi:application`

Plugins in `/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins`:

```
/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins$ ls | grep python3
asyncio_python36_plugin.so
asyncio_python3_plugin.so
python36_plugin.so
python3_plugin.so
```

Result obtained -> note python 2.7:

```
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python36_plugin.so: undefined symbol: uwsgi_legion_scrolls !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Wed May 29 18:04:24 2019] ***
compiled with version: 7.4.0 on 29 May 2019 15:30:14
os: Linux-4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019
nodename: start-tehnicka
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/anel/my_playground/webapps/p_tscze/
your processes number limit is 3618
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :5000 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:34279 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)  [GCC 7.3.0]
Set PythonHome to /home/anel/my_playground/webapps/
ImportError: No module named site
```

So please can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Q2. When comparing the result of the admin page (`./manage.py runserver`) and result obtained using `uwsgi` frontend is not the same, why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

For future references:

```
wget https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz
tar -xzvf uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz
cd uwsgi-2.0.18
python3 uwsgiconfig.py --build nolang #build binary with python3
python3 uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python nolang python36 # create a new binary
```

Run newly created binary `uwsgi` (we can link to this binary):

```
./uwsgi  --plugin-dir=/home/anel/uwsgi-2.0.18 --plugin python36 --master --http :5000 --home ~/my_playground/webapps/  --chdir ~/my_playground/webapps/p_tscze/ --module p_tscze.wsgi:application
```